# Boolean Geo Nodes Animation Mesh Glitches

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I am attempting to animate a keyboard plate being revealed using Mesh Boolean node inside geo nodes modifier, however, and this is not not the first time, for some reason during the animation the plate's mesh glitches instead of smoothly appearing.

You can see what I mean in the gif below. Can someone suggest how to fix and avoid this from happening?

Link to the blend file: [image]

[image]

Here are the nodes I am using
[image]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can see all settings you made, thx. Boolean mesh depends on several things like face direction, manifold mesh etc....and you just showed us the GN tree.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guaranty with boolean operation, but in your case, you can check "hole tolerant" option:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## More Geometry & Cleaner Topology

I find that the boolean solver works best when there's plenty of evenly-distributed geometry for both forms.

The border geometry of the flat grid component in your scene Has lots of very long, skinny triangles. Try breaking the border up into quads so that the solver has some clean topology to work with.

[image: topology idea]